# How can I use Python ctypes to call a Delphi DLL?

Tags: python, delphi, ctypes

Delphi DLL:

```pascal
function fTestExample(s: PChar): PChar;
```

```
result:result send value+ok
s[in]:string test
```

How can I use Python ctypes to call this function?

Comment: What version of Delphi is the DLL written in? `PChar` is `PAnsiChar` in D2007 and earlier, but is `PWideChar` in D2009 and later. That affects how other languages can exchange data with the DLL. Also, there is no calling convention specified on the function, so Delphi's default `register` convention will be used, which is not compatible with other programming languages. The function needs to use either `cdecl` or `stdcall` when interacting with other languages.

Comment: The other problem is the design of the function's memory allocation. How is the returned string to be deallocated.

Comment: As for ctypes, the library is documented with many examples. If you want to learn about ctypes, then start there.